# If the open() system call fails to complete, do we need to call close()?

Tags: c, linux

If open() returns a value of -1 to my program, which indicates a failure, do I still need to close the file? I read that if fopen() fails, then you do not need to call fclose() since you have not opened any files. I was wondering if this was the case for open() as well?

```
int fd = open(myfile, O_RDONLY);

if (fd == -1) {
  close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Obviously `-1` is not a valid descriptor, so calling `close` on it won't do any good.

Comment: Generally in the Unix API, when a system call fails, it does all its own cleanup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

-1 isn't a file handle, so there's no need or reason to close it.

You could have answered your own question by checking the return value of `close(-1)`. It returns -1, so that call was in error.